# Handle Android push notifications actions in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, azure, android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So I just implemented FCM in my Xamarin.Forms Android app with [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push). Everything works pretty well, the notifications arrive, they play a sound, have an icon etc. Then I wanted to add an action to my notification, it has to open a certain page in my app.

And thats were my problem comes in, Xamarin.Forms puts **all** Android content in a single Activity. Which means that opening a certain page causes the whole OnCreate of the MainActivity to load again (And the LoadApplication as well).

**My Notification**

```
var notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

notificationIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
notificationIntent.PutExtras(intent.Extras);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
    .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(text))
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
    .SetVibrate(new long[] { 0, 250, 100, 250, 0 })
    .SetLights(Color.Red, 1, 250)
    .SetContentTitle("Eindexamen")
    .SetContentText(text);
```

**FCM Payload**

```
{"data":{"message":"Notification Hub test notification", "action":"open-exam", "exam-id":"F50FC23C-B4EE-E611-80C3-000D3A218F79"}}
```

So my question is, how to open a Xamarin.Forms page without reloading the entire app on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed turned out to be rather easy.

Instead of using `ActivityFlags.ClearTop` and `ActivityFlags.NewTask` use `ActivityFlags.SingleTop`.

Then in your MainActivity.cs override the OnNewIntent method.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);

    ProcessPushNotification(intent);
}
```

Comment: could you please explain more, where your plc page? how your code will open plc page? i think this code take you to the current opening page, do you know how i can go and open specific page ?